# Expectation of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm trying to answer the following question, but from the information we are given in the question, it seems to be harder to answer in practice than it should be:

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_d)$ be RVs (d finite). The distribution is said to be normal if there is a density $p:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow R_{>0}$ wrt Lebesgue measure is given by

$p(x:\mu, \Gamma) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{det(2\pi\Gamma)}}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Gamma^{-1}(x-\mu)$

where $\mu \epsilon \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\Gamma$ is a positive dxd matrix.

Show that $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mu_k$

My take on it is that $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}x_i p(x;\mu,\Gamma)dx$

Integrate by parts and then somehow end up with $\mu$. However, if you take $u=x_i$ and $dv=p$ for the integration by parts since p is a density I keep ending up with 0 rather than $\mu_k$. If anyone could help me on whether I'm approaching this correctly or just a hint to get started I'd be so grateful!!

EDIT Solution attempt:

For simplicity let $F = -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Gamma^{-1}(x-\mu)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}F = -\Gamma^{-1}(x_k - \mu_k)$ since the derivatives with respect to $x_k$ 0f $(x-\mu), (x-\mu)^T$ are zero for every element, other than the $k_{th}$ row/column, wheer it is equal to 1.

So:

$\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}x_i p(x;\mu,\Gamma)dx$

$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{det(2\pi\Gamma)}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(\mu_k - \Gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k})exp(F)dx$

which when you separate out, the one with $\mu$ is just equal to 1 since it is $\mu$ mulitplied by the integral on the density which is 1 by definition.

And for the one on the right of the expansion, we take the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}, \Gamma$ outside of the integral, which is then the derivative of the integral of the density (which is 1), so then we have a zero.

Hence we have the desired result.

I'm not sure if I can just take the partial derivative out of the integral like that, but does anyone have any insight into my solution.

Comment: I think differentiating wrt $ x $ has no meaning, say if you consider the one variable situation. You could differentiate wrt  $ \mu_k $. For the Bivariate Normal $ (x, y) $ case this would give something like $ 0 = -E(x) - 2 \rho E(y) $ which is not of use.

Comment: Instead of differentiating F wrt $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ how about $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_k}$? Then in my final equation the $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_k}$ can be taken out of the integral, that is: $\mathbb{E}(X_k) = \mu_k - \Gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_k}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}p(x;\mu,\Gamma)dx$ and the integral is equal to 1 so the derivative wrt $\mu_k$ makes the term on the right zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are correct that the derivative of the integral is zero. But, there are cross terms involving $  \mu_k $. Your equation assumes that the variables are independent and, hence, the density function is just a product of normal one variable densities, a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, to get $ E(x) $ you can complete the square in $ y, z, u $ etc by bringing terms in $ xy, xz, xu $ etc together with $ y^2, z^2, u^2 $. These are integrated out wrt $ dydzdu.. $

$ F $  is a quadratic form in $ n $ variables consisting of sums of terms like $ ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dxz + gz^2 ... $ . Completing the square on terms involving $ y, z $ etc. you get $ ax^2 + c(y-h)^2 + g(z-k)^2 ...+ $ a constant term. The $ h, k...$ will involve $ x $. But, these will integrate out wrt $ dydzdu... $, as the range is infinite, to give a constant factor. You are then left with the one variable $ x $ integration which is the Normal expectation. You could state this in more general terms using $ i, j $.